# Force first screen of ios application to be portrait but other screens landscape ios 6+

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, rotation

I used this code for forcing my Home screen (first screen of my application) be portrait while other screens remain supporting all orientations:

```
    public class RltNavigationController : UINavigationController
{
    public RltNavigationController () : base ()
    {
    }

    public override UIInterfaceOrientationMask GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations ()
    {
        if(this.TopViewController is HomeScreen )
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait ;
        else 
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.AllButUpsideDown  ;

    }

    public override bool ShouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation (UIInterfaceOrientation toInterfaceOrientation)
    {
        // Return true for supported orientations
        if(this.TopViewController is HomeScreen )
            return (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait );
        else 
            return (toInterfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown) ;

    }


}
```

Now, suppose that the device is on the landscape orientation at home screen (Device is lanscape but screen just show portrait). Now if user go to other views, other views now show portrait while it should show landscape. What solution I can choose in order to load second views with theirs actual rotation?

**EDIT**

Thanks for all answers, Just notice that already the problem is not that I can not force the screen to be portrait. For understanding the problem please follow the scenario:

-> First screen forced to be portrait.

-> Device is landscape right and I'm in home screen(so home screen show portrait)

-> Now I switch to another screen that support all orientation

-> at another screen because the parent screen was portrait it show portrait (while because device is landscape it should show landscape)

Answer (score 0):

You can also directly select from the XIB a particular viewController be Landscape or Portrait and the same loads.

Answer (score 0):

You can not explicitly say, viewController be landscape and the view will be landscape. The way it works is, you ask the controller that is controller the screen, this may be a navigation controller, tab view controller, a modal, how they want to be able to rotate. If you have a navigation controller then all viewController will only have the rotation of your navigation controller.

There were a few tricks like subclassing the navigation controller and over the should auto rotate method, call [self.visibleViewController shouldAutoRotate]; which works for making screens rotate and not rotate, but if you have only 1 screen that supports all orientations and all the others do not, then you have a pushing/popping error where if you push or pop while in that different orientation the next viewController will be in that orientation.

Since you can't directly tell the rootViewController to explicitly rotate, the next best solutions are,

- A: Use QuartzCore to manually rotate the view yourself
- B: have a separate xib file for each orientation so when you rotate to landscape you see the landscape viewController and vice versa

Comment: Thanks,
Can you give me an example or tutorial for one of above solutions?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to create a custom navigation controller (subclass of UINavigationController) that inherits its rotation based on the currently visible view controller

Inside your custom navigation controller:

```
-(NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
}

-(BOOL) shouldAutorotate {
    return self.topViewController.shouldAutorotate;
}
```

Then inside any of the view controllers within that, add these methods:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
    return NO;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

That's for a view you DON'T want to autorotate. Modify that accordingly for views you do want to rotate.

Make sure your project settings have rotation in the orientations you want enabled, and make sure to use your custom navigation controller instead of the regular one for any view hierarchies that contain multiple possible rotations.

Note that you may run into problems if a view that is rotated is popped and the previous view is not rotatable. Off the top of my head, I'm not sure whether this will work properly.